# Defining an class with template member functions in a .ipp file

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to define a class that has a template member function so I wanted to implement an .ipp file where to define the class functions.

This is the main:

```
// Includes
#include <iostream>
#include "Monitor.hpp"

// Main
int main()
{
    Monitor monitor;

    std::cout << "Press any key to exit ..." << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

The .hpp file:

```
#pragma once

#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

class Monitor
{
private:

    // Mutex to lock data access
    std::mutex m_mutex;

    // Condition variable to wait for data availability
    std::condition_variable m_conditionVariable;

    // Flag to indicate if data is ready
    bool m_isReady;

public:

    // Constructor
    Monitor();

    // Destructor
    ~Monitor();

    // Function that captures the data
    template <class T>
    bool captureData(T& f_captureObject, bool (T::* f_captureFunction)());
};

#include "Monitor.ipp"
```

And the .ipp file:

```
Monitor::Monitor()
{
    // Init flag to data not ready
    m_isReady = false;
}

Monitor::~Monitor()
{
}

template <class T>
bool Monitor::captureData(T& f_captureObject, bool (T::* f_captureFunction)())
{
    // Lock data access
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);

    // Capture data and check if it is ready
    if ((f_captureObject.*f_captureFunction)() == true)
    {
        // If data is ready ...

        // Set data flag to ready
        m_isReady = true;

        // Notify if processing thread is waiting
        m_conditionVariable.notify_one();
    }
    else
    {
        // If data is not ready ...

        // Set data flag to not ready
        m_isReady = false;
    }

    // Return grab state
    return !m_isReady;
};
```

And I found this errors:

> E0276 name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name
>
> Error C2653   'Monitor': is not a class or namespace name

Why the .ipp file does not recognize the name "Monitor"? Thanks in advance

Comment: Appears you missed `inline` keyword on those routines.

Comment: `inline` is an issue but not the root cause. Those are compile, not link errors. Plus a template is implicitly `inline`.

Comment: You have a circular include - these two files include each other. Drop `#include "Monitor.hpp"` from `Monitor.ipp`

Comment: I agree @IgorTandetnik, but if I do that the compiler does not recognize the class Monitor on the .ipp file.

Comment: Are you including `Monitor.ipp` directly somewhere, other than at the bottom of `Monitor.hpp`? Don't; include `Monitor.hpp` instead.